# TypeError Parsing Ruby Array of Hashes

Tags: ruby, parsing, ruby-hash

I have an Array of Ruby Hashes that I'm trying to iterate so that I can parse values by key.

```
forms = {"forms":[{"id":123,"name":"John","created_at":"2021-11-23T21:41:17.000Z"},{"id":456,"name":"Joe","created_at":"2021-11-21T05:17:44.000Z"}]}

forms.each do |form|
  puts form ## {:id=>123, :name=>"John", :created_at=>"2021-11-23T21:41:17.000Z"}
  puts form["id"]
end
```

This yields the following error:

```
main.rb:4:in `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)
```

I'm admittedly a big Ruby noob, but can't figure this out. I've also tried `puts form[:id]` and `puts form[":id"]` to no avail.

**Note**: I don't have any control over the Array of Hashes that's being assigned to the `forms` variable. It's what I get back from an external API call.

Comment: `puts form ## {:id=>123,` This is not what is outputted. The output is `[:forms, [{:id=>123, ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `forms` is a `Hash`. If you do `each` on `Hash` it passes to the block [each key & value pair](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.3/Hash.html#method-i-each).

```
forms.each do |key, value|
  p key # => :forms
  p value # => [{....}]
  p value.map { |v| v[:id] }
end
```

There's also this, in case the `forms` always has the `forms` key (doesn't change)

```
forms[:forms].map { |v| v[:id] }
```